# Problem making the gun aim directly at the crosshair, cursor. (Unity2D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void shoot()
    {
      ShootingPoint.rotation = rhand.transform.rotation;
      GameObject bulletins = Instantiate(Bullet,ShootingPoint.position,ShootingPoint.rotation);
      bulletins.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(bulletins.transform.right * bulletSpeed);
      Destroy(bulletins,8);
    }
```

Shooting Point is the point right in front of the gun's front sight. Rhand is the right hand of the ragdoll. I am trying to make the ragdoll shoot while aiming towards the mouse. The shooting part works fine but the aim is not perfect. Everytime i shoot, it is a bit off from the cursor. This is my ragdoll hand aim script. Its a 2d game btw

```cs
void Update()
  {
    Vector3 playerpos = new Vector3(cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x, cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).y, 0);
    Vector3 difference = playerpos - transform.position;
    float rotationZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.x, -difference.y) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    if (Input.GetKey(mousebutton))
    {
      rb.MoveRotation(Mathf.LerpAngle(rb.rotation, rotationZ - 90f, speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime));
    }
  }
```

Edit:
Here is how off the bullets are
[image: Bullet Offset]

Answer (score 0):

Try use FixedUpdate instead of Update.

Use FixedUpdate when using Rigidbody. Set a force to a Rigidbody and it applies each fixed frame. FixedUpdate occurs at a measured time step that typically does not coincide with MonoBehaviour.Update.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html

Comment: Hey, firstly thanks for the attempt but unfortunately that did not work. I will update my original message with the output and how off the aim is. Thanks once again